# Start enterprise application client outside Netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I've created simple Enterprise Application. I have ejb, war and app-client. I'm able to deploy and run this using Netbeans. However I need to deploy and start it outside Netbeans.
I'm also able to get .ear file and using Admin Console deploy it. However I have also start an application client somehow.
I searched information about it and I get:http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1750/beaem?l=en&a=view

So I tried to input command into console:
appclient -client RoadRunnerClient.jar

However I get Exception:

> org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3431)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3452)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:256)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:269)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.java:125)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:188)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:186)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.is_a(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:352)
>           at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(Unknown Source)
>           at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.narrowProvider(SerialContext.java:355)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:327)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:271)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:430)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:169)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1040)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:688)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:657)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:148)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:428)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:513)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:384)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectClass(InjectionManagerImpl.java:210)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectClass(InjectionManagerImpl.java:202)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer$ClientMainClassSetting.getClientMainClass(AppClientContainer.java:599)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.getMainMethod(AppClientContainer.java:498)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.completePreparation(AppClientContainer.java:397)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.prepare(AppClientContainer.java:311)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.prepareACC(AppClientFacade.java:264)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.agent.AppClientContainerAgent.premain(AppClientContainerAgent.java:75)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>           at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:340)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:239)
>           ... 35 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ORBUtility.openSocketChannel(ORBUtility.java:106)
>           at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:325)
>           ... 36 more
>   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=roadrunner.Main/bean,Remote 3.x interface =common.NewSessionBeanLocal,ejb-link=RoadR
>   unner-ejb.jar#NewSessionBean,lookup=null,mappedName=,jndi-name=java:global/RoadRunner/RoadRunner-ejb/NewSessionBean!common.NewSessionBeanLocal,refType=Session into class roadrunner.Main
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:614)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:384)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectClass(InjectionManagerImpl.java:210)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectClass(InjectionManagerImpl.java:202)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer$ClientMainClassSetting.getClientMainClass(AppClientContainer.java:599)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.getMainMethod(AppClientContainer.java:498)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.completePreparation(AppClientContainer.java:397)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.prepare(AppClientContainer.java:311)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.prepareACC(AppClientFacade.java:264)
>           at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.agent.AppClientContainerAgent.premain(AppClientContainerAgent.java:75)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/roadrunner.Main/bean' in SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitialHost=localhost,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [
>   Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=roadrunner.Main/bean,Remote 3.x interface =common.NewSessionBeanLocal,ejb-link=RoadRunner-ejb.jar#NewSe
>   ssionBean,lookup=null,mappedName=,jndi-name=java:global/RoadRunner/RoadRunner-ejb/NewSessionBean!common.NewSessionBeanLocal,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for loo
>   kup is 'java:global/RoadRunner/RoadRunner-ejb/NewSessionBean!common.NewSessionBeanLocal' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/RoadRunner/RoadRunner-ejb/NewSe
>   ssionBean!common.NewSessionBeanLocal' in SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitialHost=localhost,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to
>   acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitialHost=localhost,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor
>    code: 201  completed: No]]]]
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:513)
>           ... 15 more
>   Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=roadrunner.Main/bean,Remote 3.x interface =common.NewSessionBeanLocal,ejb-link=RoadRunner-ejb.jar#NewSessionBe
>   an,lookup=null,mappedName=,jndi-name=java:global/RoadRunner/RoadRunner-ejb/NewSessionBean!common.NewSessionBeanLocal,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is
>   'java:global/RoadRunner/RoadRunner-ejb/NewSessionBean!common.NewSessionBeanLocal' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/RoadRunner/RoadRunner-ejb/NewSessionBe
>   an!common.NewSessionBeanLocal' in SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitialHost=localhost,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire
>    SerialContextProvider for SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitialHost=localhost,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code:
>   201  completed: No]]]
>           at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:174)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1040)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:688)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:657)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:148)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:428)
>           ... 17 more
>   Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/RoadRunner/RoadRunner-ejb/NewSessionBean!common.NewSessionBeanLocal' in SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb's
>   InitialHost=localhost,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitial
>   Host=localhost,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No]]
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:169)
>           ... 22 more
>   Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitialHost=localhost,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception
>    is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No]
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:276)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:430)
>           ... 24 more
>   Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3431)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3452)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:256)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:269)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.java:125)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:188)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:186)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.is_a(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:352)
>           at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(Unknown Source)
>           at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.narrowProvider(SerialContext.java:355)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:327)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:271)
>           ... 25 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>           at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:340)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:239)
>           ... 35 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ORBUtility.openSocketChannel(ORBUtility.java:106)
>           at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:325)
>           ... 36 more

>

I tried also enable Java Web Start in application RoadRunner in admin console.
Then download it and run, however then I get:
Exception:

> com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: [localhost]/**_JWSappclient/**_system/**_dyn/**_system_s1as.jnlp
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCachedFile(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadExtensionsHelper(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadExtensions(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
>    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

and Wrapped Exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: [localhost]/**_JWSappclient/**_system/**_dyn/**_system_s1as.jnlp
>    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
>    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
>    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCachedFile(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadExtensionsHelper(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadExtensions(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
>    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
>    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: [localhost]/**_JWSappclient/**_system/**_dyn/**_system_s1as.jnlp
>    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
>    ... 19 more

I have no idea what next?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change port which I use to connect:

appclient -client RoadRunnerClient.jar -targetserver localhost:[port]

I had to look which port I need to use in admin console:
ORB -> IIOP Listeners

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a configuration problem with Netbeans 6.8 with the integrated Personal Glassfish v3 server.  The server installs its IIOP service by default at 40833 but the default IIOP for JNDI is 3700.  Hence you get the error:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/RoadRunner/RoadRunner-ejb/NewSessionBean!common.NewSessionBeanLocal' in SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb's InitialHost=localhost,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitial Host=localhost,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: vmcid: SUN minor code: 201 completed: No]]
```

The solution is to add a little code to your JNDI context lookup.  Where normally you might say:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
```

instead do the following:

```
Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
            jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
            jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
            jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
            jndiProps.put("java.naming.provider.url", "iiop://localhost:40833");
            jndiProps.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "127.0.0.1");
            jndiProps.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "40833");

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
```